# Flot graph resizing error, invalid height

Tags: javascript, css, resize, flot, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to add flot graph to my page, and i'm having some problems with adding resizing to the graph. For the resize plugin to work width and height og placeholder div need to be set to 100%. 
But when i do that and want to load the graph in new window i try to call the plot method on doc ready but the height og my div is 0 althoug the containg div har height = 600px(so the placeholder div should have the same?).

```
 <div id ="ResizableContainer" class="ui-widget-content" style="width:900px;height:600px;">
    <div id="placeholderForGraph" class="graph-placeholder" ></div>
</div>
```

my.css:

```
.graph-placeholder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0; 
    position: relative;
}
```

my.js

```
$("#placeholderForGraph").text('');
$("#ResizableContainer").show();
$("#placeholderForGraph").plot([data], options);<- error
```

Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 900, height = 0

If you set heigth before calling plot, the graph will not resize in height
how can i add height to the div without destroying the resizing ability?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the Resizable (http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) plugin from jquery UI?

Comment: @Mark 
Yes, i'm doing this first  $("#ResizableContainer").resizable(); 
And the area shows and can be resized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My whole fix is a bit hacky but it works.
I first set the height to be the same as the containers

```
 $("#ResizableContainer").show();
    if ($("#placeholderForGraph").height() === 0) {
        $("#placeholderForGraph").css('min-height', $("#ResizableContainer").height()); 
    }
    plot = $.plot($("#placeholderForGraph"), []);
```

And then fill out the graph with data and options of my choice and after that i change the style og the placeholder:

```
 $("#placeholderForGraph").css('min-height', "100px");
 $("#placeholderForGraph").css('height', "100%");
 $("#placeholderForGraph").css('width', "100%");
```

Big thanks to @Raidri for help :)

Answer (score 4):

Set `min-height` for your `.graph-placeholder` to some reasonable absolute value like `100px`.

And I would also recommend setting min and max values for the resizable container (see [here](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#max-min)).

Comment: Thank you, it helped, 
the graph will show with 100px height even if the resizible container is bigger, but the graph shows :)